# Regexp.escape not escaping forward slashes?

Tags: ruby

In IRB if I pass a string like "/domain/path" to Regexp.escape it just returns it the same. I thought that forward slashes are supposed to be escaped with a backslash? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Also, the only reason why you would need to escape `/` characters is because it is your delimiter for the regexp, if you specify other type of delimiters (or make an instance of the Regexp class) you won't have this issue:

```
/^hello\/world$/  # escaping '/' just to say: "this is not the end"
%r"^hello/world$" # no need for escaping '/'
Regexp.new('^hello/world$') # no need for escaping '/'
```

Comment: For those coming here because Rubular.com says `"Forward slashes must be escaped."`, it is because Rubular.com is hardcoded to use that `/` delimiter that @Roman Gonzalez talks about in this answer.  So on Rubular.com, yes you do need to, but `Regexp.escape` does not need to.

Answer (score 2):

[Regexp.escape](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape)

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('/domain/path'))
=> /\/domain\/path/
```

**OR**

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('domain/path'))
=> /domain\/path/
```